# How can I configure desktop notification display time in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, notifications, html5

Recently Gmail introduced an HTML5-based desktop notification feature for Google Chrome users (see [this](http://www.electronista.com/articles/11/01/27/google.chrome.adds.html5.desktop.notifications/)). It's very useful, however, the notifications disappear too quickly (in about 5 seconds) and I couldn't find a way to change the display time. Ideally, I would like the notification to stay for a few minutes if there is *no* user activity (or about 15 seconds if there *is* user activity). Is that possible?

[image: Desktop Notification]

Answer (score 11):

Tip: in your Gmail settings choose "Mail notifications off".

Instead, install the Chrome extension [Mail Checker Plus for Google Mail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-gmail/oeopbcgkkoapgobdbedcemjljbihmemj?hl=en) which gives you the option to set 'show time' for notifications.

Also, this extension shows more elaborate notifications, has a "Sound notifications" option, and a few other interesting settings.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently not (well, not yet anyway):

From the "Learn more" [link](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=1075549):

> 1. Click the Settings link in the upper-right corner of Gmail.
> 2. On the General tab, select the option you'd like in the Desktop
>      Notifications section. You'll be able
>      to turn Chat notifications on or off,
>      and can also choose to turn email
>      notifications off, receive
>      notifications for all incoming email,
>      or only those Gmail marks 'important'.
> 3. Click Save.

And then on the Settings page on my Gmail account, I don't see anything about time to display. It's just this:

> - New mail notifications on - Notify me when any new message arrives in my
>     inbox
> - Important mail notifications on - Notify me only when an important
>     message arrives in my inbox
> - Mail notifications off

Comment: Yea, that's what I found too. Hopefully they'll improve this in the next release. Thanks. (BTW, it looks like Chrome 9 has already been delayed by 1/3 of a development cycle...)

Comment: Taught me something new. I like Google's release early, release often cycles. It means we can expect new features with each release.

Comment: Well, it's a year and a half later and I still can't find a way of controlling the timing of notifications. They're so fleeting that they're next to useless right now. Frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

I found that the webkit desktop notification API call `Notification.show()` displays the notification indefinitely.  Gmail probably have done something like using `setTimeout()` with `Notification.close()` to hide the notification after a few seconds. So, it is **impossible** to configure Chrome to prolong the notification display time.

Answer (score 1):

When the notification appears, there is a setting icon in the box that allows you to set what corner the notification will appear in and for how long.  When opening Chrome or Gmail in Chrome be ready to click it before it disappears.

Comment: This will take you to the list of applications that can be allowed or blocked to send you notifications, nothing else. May be this information is outdated.