# Google Desktop Notification Duration

Tags: google-chrome

I really like Chrome's desktop notifications feature, but there's one problem: The notifications remain on the screen for ~2 seconds before disappearing!

I'd like to increase the duration somehow, but Chrome itself doesn't seem to have a setting for adjusting this. Perhaps this can be accomplished through a script of some sort? Maybe even added to Chromium?

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.9.1.

Comment: see this: http://superuser.com/questions/238718/how-can-i-configure-desktop-notification-display-time-in-google-chrome